# Chance of something being fixed

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics

I'm fixing a software defect that occurs 1 in *n* test runs.  If I want to know that the probability of it being fixed is *>= p* for some *0 <= p < 1*, how many times, *m*, do I need to run the test successfully (without the defect occurring)?

Comment: This is a good question for somewhere else, but it's off-topic for MO. Try the other sites mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: I believe this is an ill-posed question, contrary to the implications of the previous comment and the 3 answers at the time of this writing.

Regardless of the values of n, p, and m, there is no way to *know*, in any sense of the word, that the probability that the defect has been fixed is >= p. (Rather, in this situation statisticians make use of *confidence intervals*.)

Comment: Good point. No assumption was stated about the probability before any testing. That's fixable, or one could ask for a p-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my statistics final which I took yesterday, the answer should be 
$m=\lceil 2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\text{InverseErf}^2[1-p]\rceil$ where InverseErf[*x*] is the [Inverse Error Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_function).

Comment: I'm not sure you can state a definitive answer like that without making more assumptions than the original asker states. What were your additional assumptions?


Comment: I was assuming that the number of times before the error occurs is roughly normally distributed - if the test is done enough times, a binomial distribution can be well-approximated by a normal distribution.  $1-\text{Erf}\left[\sqrt{\frac{t\left(\frac{1}{n}-0\right)}{2 \frac{1}{n} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}}\right]$ is the equation for the probability of making a type-1 error (mistakenly assuming that we've fixed it).

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: The number of successes before first failure is given by a geometric distribution. It's nothing like a normal distribution. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: I agree that a normal approximation is likely to be bad. If you must use a normal approximation, use $(-\infty,\frac 12)$ instead of $(-\infty, 0)$ because the count takes values in the integers.

Answer (score 2):

I guess $m>\log(1-p)/\log(1-1/n)$ works since the probability of a faulty system running 
$m$ times without defect is $(1-1/n)^m$ and this should be smaller than $1-p$.

This seems to be a homework type question (and moreover an easy one) rather than a MO-question.

Comment: Well, it's not homework.  I wish it were.  It's a bug that only QA seems to be able to reproduce.

And, yes, I probably should have just looked it up, since it's a rather simple question.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem was a little bit more difficult (roland-bacher already provided an easy, precise and correct solution) and your $n$ is big, you can also approximate the binomial distribution by a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#How_does_this_distribution_arise.3F_.E2.80.94_The_law_of_rare_events). Repeating the test $m$ times gives then the parameter $\lambda = \frac{m}{n}$ and your goal is that $m$ is big enough that $e^{-\lambda}\ge 1-p$. So $m \ge -n\ln(1-p)$. The approximation by the Poisson distribution is pretty good, for $n = 500$ and $p = 0.99$ it yields $m > 2302.585$ instead of the correct $m > 2300.28$ given by roland-bacher's formula.